# The video writer is not writing any video just an empty .mp4 file. Rest is working fine. What's the problem?

Tags: python, opencv

```
import cv2
import os


cam = cv2.VideoCapture(r"C:/Users/User/Desktop/aayfryxljh.mp4")

detector= cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
result = cv2.VideoWriter('C:/Users/User/Desktop/new.mp4',cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v'),30,(112,112))

while (True):

    # reading from frame
    ret, frame = cam.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    faces = detector.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
    size=(frame.shape[1],frame.shape[0])
    c = cv2.waitKey(1)
    # if video is still left continue creating images
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cropped = frame[y: y + h, x: x + w]
        cv2.imshow('frame', cropped)
        result.write(cropped)
# Release all space and windows once donecam.release()
result.release()
```

Should save the cropped faces video.I want to save it in .mp4 format. It Just shows an empty .mp4 file, I can't understand the issue. The code executes without any error

Comment: So `cropped` is always of size (112,112)?

Comment: Is `result.release()` ever called? Under what circumstance do you exit the while loop? Do you need to call `break` at some point if `ret` is `False`?

Comment: @DanMašek ,i want to save it in 112 x 112 that's why.

Comment: @User you were right, it was not exiting while loop. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments the while loop never finishes and so `result.release()` never gets called. It looks like the code needs a way to end the while loop. Perhaps:

```
while (True):

    # reading from frame
    ret, frame = cam.read()

    ### ADDED CODE:
    if ret == False:
        break

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    faces = detector.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
    size=(frame.shape[1],frame.shape[0])
    
    ### CHANGED CODE
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

    # if video is still left continue creating images
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cropped = frame[y: y + h, x: x + w]
        cv2.imshow('frame', cropped)
        result.write(cropped)

# Release all space and windows once donecam.release()

### ADDED CODE
cam.release()
result.release()

### ADDED CODE
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

See the example at: https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html#saving-a-video